# Why does the Chi-squared test statistic follow the Chi-squared distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, chi-squared

I know the Chi-squared test statistic is defined as:

$$\chi^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{({O_i-E_i})^2}{E_i}$$

where $O_i$ is observed data, and $E_i$ is expected.

I also know that the $\chi^2$ distribution is essentially defined as the sum of squared Gaussian random variables.

Does that mean that in order to use a Chi-squared test, one of your assumptions must be that $\sqrt{\frac{({O_i-E_i})^2}{E_i}}$ follows a Gaussian distribution? If so, is there an explanation/proof as to why this is a reasonable assumption?

Note: I didn't find any of the answers here super helpful: [Why the chi-squared statistic follows chi-squared distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815991/why-the-chi-squared-statistic-follows-chi-squared-distribution)

Comment: At follows APPROXIMATELY a chi-square distribution if the sample size is large. The central limit theorem is involved.

Comment: Right, I know approximately, forgot to mention that. I'll take another look at the CLT, it's been some time.

Comment: . . . . but there's more to this than that. See my answer below. It does not attempt to go through all the details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have $O_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(m, E_i/m),$ where $m$ is the sample size.

So $\dfrac{O_i - E_i}{\sqrt{E_i(1 - (E_i/m))}} \approx \dfrac{O_i - E_i}{\sqrt{E_i}}$ is approximately normal if $n$ is large.

However, notice that $\left( \dfrac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i} \right),\, i=1,\ldots,n$ are not independent, nor uncorrelated. They are negatively correlated because they are subject to the constraint
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n O_i = m.
$$
For example, if the throw a die $1000$ times, then the sums of the numbers of times the different outcomes occur must be $1000;$ in this case we have $n=6$ and $m=1000.$ The matrix of covariances is a $6\times6$ matrix of rank $5.$ When diagonalized, five of the diagonal entries are equal to $1$ and the sixth is $0.$ That is why the chi-square distribution has $5$ degrees of freedom. It is the distribution of the sum of $5=n-1$ independent $\operatorname N(0,1)$ random variables.

Comment: A few questions... (1) why is $O_{i}$ distributed as a Binomial? Is this an assumption? (2) Is $m$ the sum of all the $O_{i}$?

Comment: Also, for future reference, I found https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture11.pdf which actually walks through the proof step by step. Thanks!

Comment: @sir_thursday : The binomial distribution is the distribution of the number of successes in a fixed (non-random) number of independent trials with the same probability of success on each trial. Throw a die a thousand times. How many "4"s do you get? That's the number of successes in 1000 independent trials with probabilty 1/6 of success on each trial. So it's binomially distributed.

Comment: @MichaelHardy very interesting, do you have a reference explaining this and also the other statistical tests in a similar way. I can't find any.